# ipython how to execute several history lines

Tags: python, ipython

In ipython, we can use

```
_ih[32:39]
```

To show history lines between 32 and 39. How can I directly execute these history lines?

Answer (score 32):

You can execute code from previous sessions with `%recall`. See `%recall` documentation [here](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-recall).

```
#Execute all code from previous session.
%recall ~1/

#Execute all code from two sessions previous the current session.
%recall ~2/

#Execute lines 1 to 5 from previous session.
%recall ~1/1-5
```

Comment: Also try `rerun` instead of `recall` https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9303

Answer (score 21):

I use the list notation:

```
exec In[34:36]
```

also, if you use the edit function to edit a chunk, the Out list will have your code in it, so:

```
exec Out[35]
```

And my favorite:

```
edit In[34:38]
```

because I am a fat-fingered slob who can rarely get it right on the first try.

Comment: I tried your suggestion to `edit` code from the history. For me (ipython 0.12) your syntax only worked for a **single** input line: `edit In[13]`. It always failed on multiple input lines: `edit In[34:38]`. What worked instead was `edit 34-38`.

Comment: Huh!  Haven't tried this for a while, (obviously) having the same trouble with iPython 0.13...  thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Anyone give an update? None of the tips on this page worked for me. I'm on iPython 3.0.0 with Python 2.7.

Comment: Plus ONE, because I am also "am a fat-fingered slob who can rarely get it right on the first try."

Comment: This is a huge boon, and it *does* work on iPython > 3.0; `exec` is a function, however, so it's `exec(In[34:36])`, etc.

Comment: This doesn't give you the return value though. So if you do `len(x)`, you can't get the result.

Comment: 2021 update: You should add parentheses when calling `exec()` command like: `exec(In[1])`

Comment: `edit` command still works with/without parentheses

Answer (score 20):

On recent versions of iPython you use the rerun magic-comand:

`%rerun 32:39`

Documentation on that command: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-rerun

Answer (score 11):

try %recall,
check [doc of recall magic command](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-recall)

Comment: This is the updated link: http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html

Answer (score 7):

Use  the `exec` statement:

```
exec(_ih[32:39])
```

http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec

Answer (score 6):

You can create a named macro from the lines and execute them:

```
%macro foo 32-38
foo
```

This is useful if you want to execute the same set of lines more than once.  Also the lines do not need to be sequential or in order:

```
%macro bar 38 37 32-36 42
```

Comment: In new versions of IPython, you can also do `%rerun 32-38` to run them directly, or `%recall 32-38` if you want to tweak them before running.

Comment: If you create a macro, does it persist across ipython sessions?

Answer (score 3):

You can edit lines before executing them like so:

```
edit 1-5
```

Apparently the syntax changed at some point from the list-notation used in dreynold's answer.