# Run script in a loop with different arguments in each repeat

Tags: python, ipython, interactive

I often find myself running a script in ipython with a range of parameter values:

```
%run myscript.py --param 1
%run myscript.py --param 2
%run myscript.py --param 3
...
```

But then want to redo that whole lot after a small tweak to `myscript.py`.  From the shell, I could, and often do, use a construct like

```
for i in `seq 1 3` ; do python myscript.py --param $i; done
```

but for a graphical exploration (e.g. constructing a figure with outputs from those different parameters) a non-interactive mode won't work.

Is there a way to achieve this looping within ipython?

(I know that I could rewrite the script to have the loop inside, but that would be less flexible - especially while in exploratory phases, which is where ipython is often the most valuable)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613044/ipython-how-to-execute-several-history-lines

Comment: @ndpu thanks for hint. This requires that I have already typed the command for all N parameter configurations, so ok for 3 or 4 but this is not a substitute for a loop with a higher value of N (or perhaps looping over 2 parameters).  Perhaps I should have put N=30 in my example rather than 3...